# Error Cancelling Order... PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization has expired (#10601: Authorization expired)

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

We are trying to cancel an order where the PayPal Express payment has expired.  It was a duplicate order that needs to be cleaned up from the system.  However, when we try and cancel this order all we get is the following error...

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization has expired (#10601: Authorization expired).

[image]

There are no invoices or shipments on this order.  The status is just stuck on "Processing".

After walking through the code it appears to be attempting a void first inside `Mage_Paypal_Model_express->cancel()` which doesn't work since the original authorization is now expired.  I know with PayPal IPN, Magento is updated with the fact that it is now expired.  Is this a known issue with Magento 1.9 and PayPal Express?  Does anyone have a fix for this or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: I was just going to post the same issue.  I discovered the issue is that PayPal authorization has expired, so the canceling the authorization fails.   But that should NOT prevent the order from being canceled.   This is a real problem / bug.

I hate to do it, but I'm probably going to resort to forcing the order to a canceled status in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the order with an expired authorization transaction following below steps:

1. Copy txn_id from Sales -> Orders within magento admin.
2. You can search txn_id within sales_payment_transaction table.
3. Edit the row and chang field is_closed value from 0 to 1.
4. After these steps you should be able to cancel order within magento admin.